# babel-asset-pipeline 1.3.1 not working?

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, babeljs

I cant for the life of me get this asset pipeline to work.

I added:

```
compile ":babel-asset-pipeline:1.3.1"
```

to my BuildConfig.groovy

and:

```
grails.asset.babel.enabled = true
grails.asset.babel.processJsFiles = true
```

to my Config.groovy

In my application.js i just have:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js.
//
// Any JavaScript file within this directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// You're free to add application-wide JavaScript to this file, but it's generally better 
// to create separate JavaScript files as needed.
//
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
    (function($) {
        $('#spinner').ajaxStart(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }).ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    })(jQuery);
}

class Test {
    render() {
        return (
            "TEST"
        );
    }
}
```

Which *should* be converted into:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js.
//
// Any JavaScript file within this directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// You're free to add application-wide JavaScript to this file, but it's generally better
// to create separate JavaScript files as needed.
//
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

'use strict';

var _createClass = (function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ('value' in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; })();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function'); } }

if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
    (function ($) {
        $('#spinner').ajaxStart(function () {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }).ajaxStop(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    })(jQuery);
}

var Test = (function () {
    function Test() {
        _classCallCheck(this, Test);
    }

    _createClass(Test, [{
        key: 'render',
        value: function render() {
            return "TEST";
        }
    }]);

    return Test;
})();
```

According to this online tool https://babeljs.io/repl/

But it seems like my application.js is never processed. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

i just merged a pull request on that problem. 
Actually the documentation was wrong. The namespace for asset configuration is not grails.asset but grails.asset**s**

so if you update your configuration to

```
grails.assets.babel.enabled = true
grails.assets.babel.processJsFiles = true
```

it should work